# How to cast this sapply use-case as a dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

While working with `predict.knn3` I bumped into an interesting data-wrangling-ish use-case. I didn't know I could call predict using the argument `type="class"` to get the predicted levels, exactly what I needed. Therefore, I worked out a somewhat involved solution to select from each `predict()`'s result row, the level having the maximum probability. The problem was due to the `names` function not working in "vectorized" form with a matrix but only with vectors.

To illustrate the use-case before and after finding out about the `type="class"` argument:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)

data("tissue_gene_expression")
x <- tissue_gene_expression$x
y <- tissue_gene_expression$y

set.seed(1)
test_index <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
test_x <- x[test_index,]
test_y <- y[test_index]
train_x <- x[-test_index,]
train_y <- y[-test_index]

# fit the model, predict without type="class" and use sapply to build the y_hat levels
fit <- knn3(train_x, train_y, k = 1)
pred <- predict(fit, test_x)
y_hat <- sapply(1:nrow(pred), function(i) as.factor(names(pred[i,which.max(pred[i,])])))

# compare it to the solution using predict with type="class"
identical(y_hat, as.factor(predict(fit, test_x, type="class")))
[1] TRUE
```

To illustrate the issue I can do the following, see that the names function operating on a vector of named numeric elements produces the desired result whereas with a matrix will fail with NULL output:

```
names(pred[1, which.max(pred[1,])])
[1] "cerebellum"
names(pred[1:2, which.max(pred[1:2,])])
NULL
```

Assuming being unaware of this convenient `type="class"` in the `predict.knn3` function; is there a simpler way using tidyverse and dplyr to replace this sapply with? Or any other simpler way to implement this use-case?

```
y_hat <- sapply(1:nrow(pred), function(i) as.factor(names(pred[i, which.max(pred[i,])])))
```

I'm after something like the following but it doesn't work:

```
as_tibble(predict(fit, test_x)) %>% mutate(y_hat=names(which.max(.[row_number(),])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing operations on rows can be a bit messy with `dplyr` I find. This should work though. Taking a guess, this is not the most computationally efficient.

```
solution <- as_tibble(predict(fit, test_x)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(as.data.frame(.) %>%
       mutate(., y_hat = names(.)[which.max(select(., everything()))])
  )

solution %>%
  slice(18:22)

# A tibble: 5 x 8
  cerebellum colon endometrium hippocampus kidney liver placenta y_hat     
       <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>     
1          1     0           0           0      0     0        0 cerebellum
2          1     0           0           0      0     0        0 cerebellum
3          0     1           0           0      0     0        0 colon     
4          0     1           0           0      0     0        0 colon     
5          0     1           0           0      0     0        0 colon
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the predictions are a matrix, you can directly apply `which.max` to each row.

```r
pred <- predict(fit, test_x)
labels <- colnames(pred)
labels[apply(pred, 1, which.max)]
```

Answer (score 2):

See `?max.col`:

```
colnames(pred)[max.col(pred)]

#or dplyr

library (dplyr)

pred%>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(y_hat = names(.)[max.col(.)])
```

Comment: @SkyWalker see edit for ```dplyr``` approach. It should be speedy because ```max.col``` is vectorized

Answer (score 1):

I have to use melt to get the matrix into long format:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(pred) %>% 
    group_by(Var1) %>% 
    top_n(1,wt=value) %>% pull(Var2)
```

Comment: If you do this, I would use `tidyr` now with `pivot_longer()`. Per the github page: "reshape2 is retired: only changes necessary to keep it on CRAN will be made. We recommend using tidyr instead."